# jQuery width() messes up CSS width

Tags: jquery, css

I have two input elements, one is input file and one is input readonly text . I settled the main input file with a certain width in css file as :

```
.myinputfile { width: 78% !important; max-width: 78% !important }
```

So with jQuery .offset() I put the input readonly text at the same position of input file like :

[image: same offset two elements]

So I added now this jQuery line :

```
$("#mydescfilename").width( $("#myinputfile").width() );
```

and I see this jQuery .width() messes CSS's width of input file as follow:

[image: width messed up]

I've tried also with:

```
var descfilenamevar = $("#myinputfile").width() + 'px';
$("#mydescfilename").css('width', descfilenamevar);
```

but without success due it causes same result as with setting the .width() directly...

Considering my goal is to put that readonly input text right to the input file button to always show the filename adjusting the .offsetX adding button's length, why does this
jQuery's .width() messing the css's width up?... Is there an alternative or a trick?.. Thanks to all! Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to do this via CSS directly since you have separate classes for both, using the `display: inline` property.

Working example snippet:

```css
.myinputfile {
  display: inline;
  width: 78%
}

.mydescfilename {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="myinputfile">
  [...box...]
</div>
<div class="mydescfilename">
  my file name
</div>
```

This way you can also provide any extra margins you would like to have between the two classes

Comment: Hello @Aneesh , after added divs and settled `display:inline` as you suggested, then  using extra margins like `$("#mydescfilename").css('margin-left', 100);` doesn't move the input readonly text to left to stay left of the input file's button so I had to play a bit with offset in jQuery, not so elegant because having to play with width too but at least now it works...